# Hover over Link from Material-UI not working

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to hover over Link from material UI but it is not working. The CSS does not apply for some reason and I cant find out why. And the class Button is also not working on buttons.
Why it is not reading those CSS? Using the latest version of MUI.

```
import {Link , Button} from '@mui/material';
import {makeStyles} from '@mui/styles';

const useStyle = makeStyles({
    MenuItems : {
        '& li' : {
            display : 'inline',
            marginRight : '2rem',
            '&:hover' : {
                color : '#E0475B'
            }
        }
    },
    Link : {
        '&:hover' : {
            color : '#E0475B'
        }
    },
    Button : {
        backgroundColor : '#E0475B' , 
        color : 'white',
        fontSize : '1.5rem'
    }

})

const HomeMenu = () => {
    const classes = useStyle();
    return ( 
        <div className="Body">
            <AppBar style={{backgroundColor : 'white'}}>
                <Toolbar className = {classes.Toolbar}>
                    <div className={classes.MenuItems}>
                        <ul>
                            <li>
                                <Link href = '/' underline = 'none' style={{color : 'black'}} className={classes.Link} >Home</Link>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <Link href = '/' underline = 'none' style={{color : 'black'}} className={classes.Link}>About Us</Link>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <Link href = '/' underline = 'none' style={{color : 'black'}} className={classes.Link}>Our Mission</Link>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <Link href = '/' underline = 'none' style={{color : 'black'}} className={classes.Link}>Contact Us</Link>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div className={classes.ButtonItems}>
                        <ul>
                            <li><Button variant='contained' className = {classes.Button}>Sign Up</Button></li>
                            <li><Button variant = 'contained' className = {classes.Button}>Log In</Button></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </Toolbar>

            </AppBar>
        </div>
     );
}
 
export default HomeMenu;
```

Comment: Your `inline` style is overriding the `hover` styles. Your [code](https://codesandbox.io/s/links-material-demo-forked-u7cw4?file=/demo.js) after removing `inline` style and moving it to `class`.

Answer (score 1):

Your inline style has higher specificity than the one from `makeStyles` which uses class name selector, just remove it and your styles will work again:

```
<Link
  href="/"
  underline="none"
  // comment this line -------------> style={{ color: "black" }}
  className={classes.Link}
>
```

[image: Codesandbox Demo]